# Play 2.4 Form field value bind to type java.time.LocalDate

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to create a form with a field which value type is java.time.LocaDate.

```
def javaLocalDateForm = Form(single(
  "date" -> of[LocalDate]
))
```

However, it gives me a compilation error.

```
Cannot find Formatter type class for java.time.LocalDate. Perhaps you will need to import play.api.data.format.Formats._
```

Tried to import `play.api.data.format.Formats._` but compiler still gives me the same error.

Is there any way I can bind form field value to java.time.LocalDate?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are pre-defined `Formatter`s for Joda's `LocalDate` and `java.util.Date`, but not (yet) for the Java 8 `LocalDate` class.

So you could either use the Joda library (for now), or build your own `Formatter[java.time.LocalDate]`, possibly by wrapping around one of these other pre-defined `Formatter`s and converting to the Java `LocalDate` class.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
class LocalDateFormatter extends play.api.data.format.Formatter[LocalDate] {
  import play.api.data.FormError

  override def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], LocalDate] = try{
    Right(
      LocalDate.parse(data(key))
    )
  }
  catch{
    case _:Throwable => Left(Seq(new FormError(key, Seq("error.date"))))
  }

  override def unbind(key: String, value: LocalDate): Map[String, String] = Map(key -> value.toString)
}
```

and then

```
// play scala form binders
object UtilsDate{
  import play.api.data.FieldMapping
  def of[DateTime](implicit binder: play.api.data.format.Formatter[DateTime]): FieldMapping[DateTime] = FieldMapping[DateTime]()(binder)
  val formBinder = of(new LocalDateFormatter())
}
```

in your code you can then use

```
val myForm = Form(tuple("name" -> nonEmptyText, "date" -> UtilsDate.formBinder))
```